# Automatic wrapping of displayed long formula (e.g., with the same algorithm used for inlined formulae)

Tags: line-breaking, multline

Typographers warn against automatic wrapping of long formulae; however, there are cases in which this makes sense. Here is one:
[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum,framed,amsmath}
\newcommand{\wrapMe}{1A+2B+3C+4D+5E+6F+7G+8H+9I+10J+11K+12L+13M+14N+15O+16P+17Q+18R+19S+20T+21U+22V+24W+25X+25Y+26Z}
\begin{document}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  See how~$\zeta=\wrapMe$ wraps nicely within the text.
  I can also manually produce an even nicer displayed version
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
      \zeta  = & 1A+2B+3C+4D+5E+6F+7G+8H\\
      & + 9I+ 10J+11K+12L+13M+14N+15O\\
      & +16P+ 17Q+18R+19S+20T+21U+22V\\
      & +24W+25X+25Y+26Z
    \end{split}
  \end{equation}
  Can this be done automatically? Let's try!
  \begin{equation}
    \zeta =\wrapMe
  \end{equation}
  \par
  \lipsum[\inputlineno]
  \par
  \begin{minipage}{0.9\columnwidth}
    \begin{framed}
      \begin{equation}
        \zeta =\wrapMe
      \end{equation}
    \end{framed}
  \end{minipage}
  \par
  \lipsum[\inputlineno]
  \par
  \begin{minipage}{0.7\columnwidth}
    \begin{framed}
      \begin{equation}
        \zeta = \wrapMe
      \end{equation}
    \end{framed}
  \end{minipage}
  \par
  \lipsum[\inputlineno]
  \par

  \begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
    \begin{framed}
      \begin{equation}
        \zeta =\wrapMe
      \end{equation}
    \end{framed}
  \end{minipage}
  \par
  \lipsum[\inputlineno]
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\columnwidth}
    \begin{framed}
      \begin{equation}
        \zeta =\wrapMe
      \end{equation}
    \end{framed}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

**Clarification**
Ideally, a macro named, e.g., `\wrap`, will be used to wrap `\wrapMe`:

```
  \begin{equation}
    \zeta = \wrap[\lineLength - 5ex]{\wrapMe}
  \end{equation}
```

but, there could be other clever schemes to automatically determine the "correct" wrapping width.

Comment: `\def\[{\medskip$\displaystyle}\def\]{$\medskip}`

Comment: Sorry, I did not get it. How can this be used to wrap the contents of `\wrapMe` in `\[\zeta =\wrapMe\]`? Will edit to clarify.

Comment: Did you have a look at the dmath environment from breqn?

Comment: @ArnoMittelbach -- `breqn` is promising and well intentioned, but unfortunately, it has never gotten out of beta.  so one's mileage may vary.

Comment: @Symbol1 I think you should make that the answer (It's what I was going to suggest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will break before plus and minus signs, other binary operators can be added in a similar fashion.

The optional argument to `wrapeqn` is the total width, default 90% of the allotted width.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum,amsmath}

\newcommand{\wrapMe}{%
  1A+2B+3C+4D+5E+6F+7G+8H+9I+10J+11K+12L+13M+14N+
  15O+16P+17Q+18R+19S+20T+21U+22V+24W+25X+25Y+26Z%
}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{wrapeqn}[2][.9\displaywidth]
 {\begin{minipage}{#1}\openup\jot\change@operations
  \@hangfrom{$\displaystyle#2{}$}$\displaystyle}
 {$\end{minipage}}
\newcommand{\change@operations}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`+\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\prebin@plus
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`-\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\prebin@minus
  \mathcode`+="8000 \mathcode`-="8000
}
\edef\prebin@plus{\penalty\binoppenalty\mathchar\the\mathcode`+\noexpand\nobreak}
\edef\prebin@minus{\penalty\binoppenalty\mathchar\the\mathcode`-\noexpand\nobreak}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

See how~$\zeta=\wrapMe$ wraps nicely within the text.
I can also manually produce an even nicer displayed version
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\zeta={} & 1A+2B+3C+4D+5E+6F+7G+8H\\
         & + 9I+ 10J+11K+12L+13M+14N+15O\\
         & +16P+ 17Q+18R+19S+20T+21U+22V\\
         & +24W+25X+25Y+26Z
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Can this be done automatically? Let's try!
\begin{equation*}
\begin{wrapeqn}{\zeta =}
\wrapMe
\end{wrapeqn}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}
\begin{wrapeqn}[.8\columnwidth]{\zeta =}
\wrapMe
\end{wrapeqn}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Combining `\hangindent` and `\hangafter`, you can align the formula as what you did in `split`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\newdimen\tempindent
\settowidth\tempindent{$0<\mathopen{}$}
\hangafter1\hangindent\tempindent
\medskip\noindent
$\displaystyle0<(k+2)(1-[wz+h+j-q]^2-[(gk+2g+k+1)(h+j)+h-z]^2-[16(k+1)^3(k+2)(n+1)^2+1-f^2]^2-[2n+p+q+z-e]^2-[e^3(e+2)(a+1)^2+1-o^2]^2-[(a^2-1)y^2+1-x^2]^2-[16r^2y^4(a^2-1)+1-u^2]^2-[n+l+v-y]^2-[(a^2-1)l^2+1-m^2]^2-[ai+k+1-l-i]^2-[((a+u^2(u^2-a))^2-1)(n+4dy)^2+1-(x+cu)^2]^2-[p+l(a-n-1)+b(2an+2a-n^2-2n-2)-m]^2-[q+y(a-p-1)+s(2ap+2a-p^2-2p-2)-x]^2-[z+pl(a-p)+t(2ap-p^2-1)-pm]^2)$
\par\medskip

\lipsum[2]
```

One can also import the example from **The TeXBook**.

[image]

```
\newdimen\varunit
\varunit=3.2pt
\hfill\vtop{\null
\baselineskip6\varunit
\parfillskip0pt
\parshape 19
-18.25\varunit 36.50\varunit
-30.74\varunit 61.48\varunit
-38.54\varunit 77.07\varunit
-44.19\varunit 88.39\varunit
-48.47\varunit 96.93\varunit
-51.70\varunit 103.40\varunit
-54.08\varunit 108.17\varunit
-55.72\varunit 111.45\varunit
-56.68\varunit 113.37\varunit
-57.00\varunit 114.00\varunit
-56.68\varunit 113.37\varunit
-55.72\varunit 111.45\varunit
-54.08\varunit 108.17\varunit
-51.70\varunit 103.40\varunit
-48.47\varunit 96.93\varunit
-44.19\varunit 88.39\varunit
-38.54\varunit 77.07\varunit
-30.74\varunit 61.48\varunit
-18.25\varunit 36.50\varunit
\frenchspacing
\noindent
\hbadness 6000
\tolerance 9999
\pretolerance 0
$\displaystyle0<(k+2)(1-[wz+h+j-q]^2-[(gk+2g+k+1)(h+j)+h-z]^2-[16(k+1)^3(k+2)(n+1)^2+1-f^2]^2-[2n+p+q+z-e]^2-[e^3(e+2)(a+1)^2+1-o^2]^2-[(a^2-1)y^2+1-x^2]^2-[16r^2y^4(a^2-1)+1-u^2]^2-[n+l+v-y]^2-[(a^2-1)l^2+1-m^2]^2-[ai+k+1-l-i]^2-[((a+u^2(u^2-a))^2-1)(n+4dy)^2+1-(x+cu)^2]^2-[p+l(a-n-1)+b(2an+2a-n^2-2n-2)-m]^2-[q+y(a-p-1)+s(2ap+2a-p^2-2p-2)-x]^2-[z+pl(a-p)+t(2ap-p^2-1)-pm]^2)+(k+2)(1-[wz+h+j-q]^2-[(gk+2g+k+1)(h+j)+h-z]^2-[16(k+1)^3(k+2)(n+1)^2+1-f^2]^2-[2n+p+q+z-e]^2-[e^3(e+2)(a+1)^2+1-o^2]^2-[(a^2-1)y^2+1-x^2]^2-[16r^2y^4(a^2-1)+1-u^2]^2-[n+l+v-y]^2-[(a^2-1)l^2+1-m^2]^2-[ai+k+1-l-i]^2-[((a+u^2(u^2-a))^2-1)(n+4dy)^2+1-(x+cu)^2]^2-[p+l(a-n-1)+b(2an+2a-n^2-2n-2)-m]^2-[q+y(a-p-1)+s(2ap+2a-p^2-2p-2)-x]^2-[z+pl(a-p)+t(2ap-p^2-1)-pm]^2)+(k+2)(1-[wz+h+j-q]^2-[(gk+2g+k+1)(h+j)+h-z]^2-[16(k+1)^3(k+2)(n+1)^2+1-f^2]^2-[2n+p+q+z-e]^2-[e^3(e+2)(a+1)^2+1-o^2]^2-[(a^2-1)y^2+1-x^2]^2-[16r^2y^4(a^2-1)+1-u^2]^2-[n+l+v-y]^2-[(a^2-1)l^2+1-m^2]^2-[ai+k+1-l-i]^2-[((a+u^2(u^2-a))^2-1)(n+4dy)^2+1-(x+cu)^2]^2-[p+l(a-n-1)+b(2an+2a-n^2-2n-2)-m]^2-[q+y(a-p-1)+s(2ap+2a-p^2-2p-2)-x]^2-[z+pl(a-p)+t(2ap-p^2-1)-pm]^2)$
}

\end{document}
```